# pt-query-digest --type binlog (percona-toolkit) gives empty output with MariaDB/Galera 10.1

Tags: mariadb, binlog, mariadb-10.1, mysqlbinlog, percona-toolkit

My installed versions of MariaDB and Percona Toolkit on MacBook:

```
brew info percona-toolkit
percona-toolkit: stable 3.0.10 (bottled), HEAD
Percona Toolkit for MySQL
https://www.percona.com/software/percona-toolkit/
/usr/local/Cellar/percona-toolkit/3.0.10 (244 files, 8.4MB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2018-05-31 at 09:52:48
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/percona-toolkit.rb
==> Dependencies
Required: mysql ✔, openssl ✔
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
```

DB server versions:

```
show global variables like '%version%';
+-------------------------+---------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                     |
+-------------------------+---------------------------+
| innodb_version          | 5.6.36-82.1               |
| protocol_version        | 10                        |
| slave_type_conversions  |                           |
| version                 | 10.1.26-MariaDB           |
| version_comment         | Source distribution       |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                    |
| version_compile_os      | Linux                     |
| version_malloc_library  | system                    |
| version_ssl_library     | OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014 |
| wsrep_patch_version     | wsrep_25.19               |
+-------------------------+---------------------------+
10 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Funny is in order to install percona-toolkit I had to install Oracle MySQL and afterwords change back to MariaDB

```
brew install mariadb
brew unlink mariadb
brew install percona-toolkit
brew unlink mysql
brew link mariadb
```

We use Galera cluster with row based replication:

```
show global variables like 'binlog_format';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| binlog_format | ROW   |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I did a simple use case:

```
mysqlbinlog  mysql-bin.0013* > all.sql

pt-query-digest --type binlog all.sql
all.sql:   1% 37:37 remain
(...)
all.sql:  96% 01:23 remain
all.sql:  98% 00:30 remain

# 2417.5s user time, 51.4s system time, 89.16M rss, 4.24G vsz
# Current date: Fri Jun  1 07:42:57 2018
# Hostname: aukVivi0009
# Files: all.sql
# Overall: 0 total, 2.05k unique, 0 QPS, 0x concurrency __________________
# Time range: 2018-05-26 02:00:54 to 2018-05-31 08:05:28
# Attribute          total     min     max     avg     95%  stddev  median
# ============     ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= =======
# Query size        10.68G       6 287.51k  492.88  833.10   1.92k  107.34

# Profile
# Rank        Query ID    Response time Calls       R/Call      V/M   Item
# =========== =========== =========== =========== =========== ===== ======
```

why is the output empty?
Is `pt-query-digest` not compatible with MariaDB? Changes in binlog format? Any workaround?

Comment: See if this helps:  http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/reading-rbr-binary-logs-with-pt-query-digest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [*Reading RBR binary logs with pt-query-digest*](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/reading-rbr-binary-logs-with-pt-query-digest) and [*LP #1377887: pt-query-digest fails to parse binary log with RBR events*](https://jira.percona.com/browse/PT-1245)

That bug report is over 2 years old and ranked as "low" priority.  Suggest you add a comment to clue Percona in that there is interest in getting it fixed.